# C++ program (ROS node) for working with several cameras is slow in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, opencv, ros

I wrote a C++ program (ROS Node) in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) to get camera images and publish them on ROS topics.

I have two Lumenera Cameras, which can output 90 frames per second with a size of 2048 * 2048.

When I connect one camera, it publishes 90 frames per second, which is equal to the highest frame rate of my cameras. However, when I connect two cameras, the publishing rate decreases to 45 per second.

For working with cameras, I create one thread for each one. Each thread reads and publishes images of one camera. The image below shows my system `CPU` and `RAM` during running the program (ROS Node) for two cameras:
[image]

As is shown in the image, the `CPU` and `RAM` still have free capacity. Therefore, I do not know why the number of frames decreases.

An important part of the code for more information is in the following, if you want more information, please see the `src` folder of this repository on GitHub: https://github.com/farhad-dalirani/lumenera_camera_package

```
#define LUMENERA_LINUX_API
#undef LUMENERA_MAC_API
#undef LUMENERA_WINDOWS_API

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#include <lucamapi.h>
#include <lucamerr.h>
#include "Camera.h"

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

using namespace cv;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void publish_camera_on_topic(std::vector<Camera> cameras, const std::vector<ros::Publisher> publishers, const int camera_index)
{ 
  ROS_INFO_STREAM( "Start thread for " << camera_index << "." << std::endl);

  int frameSize;
  BYTE *imagePtr;

  // frame id
  int frame_id = 0;

  cv_bridge::CvImage img_bridge;
  sensor_msgs::Image img_msg;

  while (ros::ok() && ros::master::check()) {
    // Grab and display a single image from each camera
    
    imagePtr = cameras[camera_index].getRawImage();

    frameSize = cameras[camera_index].getFrameSize();

    cameras[camera_index].createRGBImage(imagePtr,frameSize);

    unsigned char* pImage = cameras[camera_index].getImage();
    if (NULL != pImage) {

      Mat image(cameras[camera_index].getMatSize(), CV_8UC3, pImage, Mat::AUTO_STEP);

      // release asap
      cameras[camera_index].releaseImage(); 

      //cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2RGB,3);

      // publish on ROS topic
      std_msgs::Header header; // empty header
      header.seq = frame_id; // user defined counter
      header.stamp = ros::Time::now(); // time
      img_bridge = cv_bridge::CvImage(header, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::RGB8, image);
      img_bridge.toImageMsg(img_msg); // from cv_bridge to sensor_msgs::Image
      publishers[camera_index].publish(img_msg); // ros::Publisher pub_img = node.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>("topic", queuesize);

    }

    // increase frame Id
    frame_id = frame_id + 1;
  }

  ROS_INFO_STREAM( "ROS closing for thread of camera " << camera_index << " recieved." << std::endl);
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  std::thread * th;

  // ROS node name
  ros::init(argc, argv, "lumenera_camera_node");
    
  // ros node handle
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  // ros rate Hz
  ros::Rate rate(90);

  // print start of node
  ROS_INFO("Node: [lumenera_camera_node] has been started.");



  
  bool displaySobelImage = false;
  if (argc > 1) {
    displaySobelImage = true;
  }


  int numCameras = LucamNumCameras();
  
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("Found " << numCameras << " camera" << std::string((1 == numCameras) ? "" : "s") << endl);

  if (0 == numCameras) {
    return 0;
  }

  // For now, limit ourselves to 1 camera
  numCameras = std::max(numCameras, 1);
  std::vector<Camera> cameras(numCameras);

  // Initialize each camera
  for(size_t i=0; i < cameras.size(); i++) {
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Initializing Camera #" << i+1 << endl);
    cameras[i].init(i+1, displaySobelImage ? "Sobel" : "");
  }

  // Start streaming on each camera
  for(size_t i=0; i < cameras.size(); i++) {
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Starting streaming on Camera #" << i+1 << endl);
    cameras[i].startStreaming();
  }

  //
  const int scale  = 1;
  const int delta  = 0;
  const int ddepth = CV_16S;

  // image publisher 
  // for each camera create an publisher
  std::vector<ros::Publisher> publishers;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cameras.size(); i++) {
    char topic_name[200];
    sprintf(topic_name, "/lumenera_camera_package/%d", i + 1);
    publishers.push_back(nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>(topic_name, 10));
  }
  
  // work with each camera on a seprate thread
  std::vector<std::thread *> thread_vector;
  for(size_t camera_index=0; camera_index < cameras.size(); camera_index++) {
    th = new std::thread;
    *th = std::thread(publish_camera_on_topic, cameras, publishers, camera_index);
    thread_vector.push_back(th);
  }

  ros::spin();

  for(size_t camera_index=0; camera_index < cameras.size(); camera_index++) {
    thread_vector[camera_index]->join();
    delete thread_vector[camera_index];
  }


  for(size_t camera_index=0; camera_index < cameras.size(); camera_index++) {
    cameras[camera_index].stopStreaming();
  }

  ROS_INFO("Node: [lumenera_camera_node] has been Ended.");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Am I right that the images are 8-bit 3-channel data? So 2k * 2k * 3 * 90 works out at around 1.13 GB per second. What is the interface for these cameras? Are they USB? You might be saturating your bus. This is around the maximum capability of USB 3.2.

Comment: Yes, the Images are 2K and RGB-8. Both cameras are connected to two separate USB 3.

Comment: When you say separate USB 3, are you talking about _ports_ or _host controllers_? There is a difference. A controller may manage more than one port, and the controller has a maximum throughput also.

Comment: @paddy How can I find the bus capacity? 
Do programs have a limitation on bus usage bandwidth?

Comment: @paddy I meant two different USB ports that are separately connected to the bus. For example, it is not a USB hub that converts one USB port to several USB port.

Comment: I'm not talking about an external hub. I'm talking about a controller on your motherboard. Or possibly even data lane sharing between controllers depending on the architecture. If it's a bandwidth issue, it has absolutely nothing to do with your program. It would be a limitation of the hardware and communication protocol. I am still theorizing, but I wouldn't be surprised if this is the problem. I suggest you try telling the cameras to operate at lower rates experiment to determine at what point your frames from one camera or the other are throttled.

Comment: Also, open up your machine and look where the USB 3 wires go. Many motherboards provide more than one USB 3 header, and usually this means they are on separate controllers. If you're using the ports that are soldered onto the rear plate, then they are probably all on the same controller. So, if you have front I/O with USB 3, it's likely to connect to a header instead. Try plugging one camera into that, and the other into the rear.

Comment: @paddy thank you, I will check and let you know.

Comment: I would agree this appears to be an issue with hardware throughput. You can also try to verify by timing how long `getRawImage()` takes to return with one/two cameras.